# Batch file commands based on time in log file?

Tags: batch-file, logging, time, find

Other questions always refer to the current time, but I need the script to do something based on the time value in a certain string in a log file.

The log file contains lines of this format:

Billy - 13:42:14

I need the batch file to calculate the amount of time that has passed since a predefined time (ex. 13:00:00). So in this case the output would be 00:42:14.

How can I get the script to find the string containing "Billy" but then look at and analyse the time value at the end of the line to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date/time maths is not native to Windows `cmd`/batch; let me suggest to use another language like PowerShell, VBScript or JavaScript, which are all native to Windows and are capable of true date/time arithmetics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following script?
A predefined time and log file can be set by "pretime" and "logfile", respectively. "Billy" is searched from the log file. And the difference time is output. It was responded even when there are some lines included "Billy".

Log file:

```
aBilly - 13:42:14
Billy - 13:42:14
cBilly - 13:42:14
Billy - 13:13:14
dBilly - 13:42:14
```

Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set pretime=13:00:00
set logfile=sample.log

call :timetosec %pretime%
set pretime=!sec!
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%i in (%logfile%) do (
    if %%i==Billy (
        call :timetosec %%k
        set /a d=!sec!-%pretime%
        call :sectotime %d%
        echo !outtime!
    )
)
goto :EOF

:timetosec
set t=%1
set /a h=%t:~0,2%*3600
set /a m=%t:~3,2%*60
set s=%t:~6,2%
set /a sec=%h%+%m%+%s%
goto :EOF

:sectotime
set /a m=%d%/60
set /a s=%d%-(%m%*60)
set /a h=%m%/60
set /a m=%m%-(%h%*60)
if %h% lss 10 set h=0%h%
if %m% lss 10 set m=0%m%
if %s% lss 10 set s=0%s%
set outtime=%h%:%m%:%s%
goto :EOF
```

Output:

```
00:42:14
00:13:14
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your time :)